# Unable to embed a local HLS stream into a browser

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a HLS stream publishing locally using a Mediamtx server on http://127.0.0.1:8888/stream. I can verify this stream is up by pointing Chrome directly to it.

I'm now trying to embed this stream into a webpage. I'm trying the simplest static webpage at this point, to eliminate any other sources of error, so I'm using the following page.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='player'>
            <video width="352" height="288" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/stream/"  type="application/x-mpegURL" controls autoplay>
            </video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This shows a static player that does not play. There is no console output. Perhaps crucially the Mediamtx server I'm running reports is capable of reporting connections and when I point my browser to the stream directly I see a connection established, whereas when I load the static page, nothing happens.

I've tried running Chrome in CORS disabled mode, although I believe this shouldn't be an issue in this case.

Comment: Browser native HLS support varies by platform. The stream works when loaded directly via the link because Mediamtx uses the `hls.js` player internally. Check out the documentation: https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx?tab=readme-ov-file#web-browsers-1. You will need to pass `http://<host>:<port>/mystream/index.m3u8` to the browser/player.